# Getting specific columns from Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've been beating myself up with this and can't seem to be able to get my JSON to only display the title and description of the rooms should they be live.  I have tried using `return $this->hasMany('Room')->select(array('id', 'title', 'description'));` but it returns nothing at all for rooms.

Can anyone help? I'm sure this must be very simple to achieve as I understood Laravel Eloquent to be simplistic for this kind of task.

JSON

```
[
    {
        id: 1,
        building_title: "Drum Castle"
        room: [
            {
                id: 1,
                building_id: 7,
                title: "Snooker Room",
                description: "Full Description",
                live: 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Building Model

```
public function room()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Room');
}
```

Room Model

```
public function building()
{
   return $this->belongsTo('Building', 'building_id');
}
```

Controller

```
$buildings = Building::with('room')->get();
```

Comment: What is the output of `Building::with('room')->get();`?

Comment: The JSON above is an example of what I get with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt at restricting the fields on the relationship failed because you didn't select the `building_id` field.  If you don't get this field, Laravel has no idea on which rooms belong to which buildings (think about eager loaded relationships).

One method to do what you want is to override the `toArray()` method (which is called by `toJson()`), on either the Building or the Room.

Another option is to set the hidden/visible attributes on your Room model.  The attributes will govern which fields are hidden/visible when converting to an array.

```
class Room extends Eloquent {
    protected $hidden = array('building_id', 'live');
    // or
    protected $visible = array('id', 'title', 'description');

    // rest of class
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly.  I hadn't considered using hidden.  Thank you